# Etimologia dos chatos: o piolho-da-púbis é chato porque chateia ou porque é achatado?

Tags: etimologia

A palavra latina ***plattus***, que significa *plano*, deu origem ao português [***chato***](http://www.aulete.com.br/chato), que tem vários significados:

1. que é plano, tem pouca profundidade: *barco de fundo chato, pé chato*.
2. que aborrece, chateia: *filme chato, aquele tipo é um chato*.
3. e por fim, um bichinho muito amoroso, o [piolho-da-púbis](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piolho-da-p%C3%BAbis).

Ora, pelas [imagens que vi](https://www.google.pt/search?q=crab%20lice&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=643&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiArOyMpp_KAhXDvBoKHU-0DOIQ_AUIBigB) o piolho-da-púbis parece-me ser chato no sentido (1), relativamente achatado, e imagino que o seja também no sentido (2), que chateie à brava.

Portanto o que eu pergunto é: **quando é que surgiram os vários significados?**

Imagino que o (1), que é o original da palavra latina, seja o primeiro. Mas (a) depois surgiu primeiro o (2), e mais tarde ter-se-á chamado *chato* ao piolho por ele chatear? Ou (b) chamou-se primeiro *chato* ao piolho, possivelmente por causa da sua forma, e mais tarde chamou-se *chato* às pessoas maçadoras por elas maçarem como os piolhos-da-púbis?

**Atualização.** Encontrei mais alguma informação que poderá ser útil a quem queira pegar nesta questão. Vem no dicionário Houaiss sem mais pormenores que segundo Antenor Nascentes no *Dicionário etimológico da língua portuguesa* é a hipótese (a) que está correta. Por outro lado, não sei se será muito relevante mas partilho na mesma, o bichinho em espanhol chama-se [*ladilla*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MmLo4Lx), que não tem nada que ver com *plano*, mas na Argentina, Uruguai, Venezuela, México e Cuba também significa uma coisa ou pessoa aborrecida; e na Venezuela [*ladillar*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MmMZFtI) significa *chatear*.

Comment: Se "chato" teve a sua denominação originada em um laboratório eu diria que é devido ao formato.  Mas acredito que tenha sido a outra possibilidade:  a origem popular. pois esse ectoparasita é muito incomodativo, provoca prurido intenso e a necessidade de coçar muito principalmente à noite.  Bem, até aí eu não respondi nada.  Por isso postei como comentário.

Comment: @Centaurus também não me parece que o nome "chato" fosse dado em laboratório. O bicho já deve ser conhecido desde tempos imemoriais, antes de existirem laboratórios.

Comment: @Centaurus Mas mesmo sendo de origem popular, a questão mantém-se: o pessoal chamou primeiro chato ao piolho e depois às pessoas, ou foi o contrário

Comment: Jacinto,  "at a guess": primeiro veio o adjetivo/substantivo "chato" para designar aqueles que enchem a nossa paciência.  Como o piolho também incomoda bastante ao infeliz que o abriga, transferimos o substantivo para o quase microscópico inquilino.

Comment: @Centaurus É possível. É preciso averiguar.

Comment: A gíria `chato` veio como analogia para o nome popular do inseto `chato` - que causa coçadura e irritação principalmente na virilha, quando achar uma fonte coloco aqui a resposta. Várias gírias e adjetivos de hoje em dia, tem a origem "palavrões" de outrora ou termos relacionados a área genital.

Answer (score 4):

A gíria ***chato*** vem da alusão ao **piolho chato** que ataca principalmente os pelos pubianos, causando irritação.

> [..] o uso do termo ‘chato,’ atribuído ao piolho, passou a também significar os humanos de comportamento igualmente irritante. 
>   <sub>[< LIMA, RAYMUNDO DE: Sobre chatices e chatos (II) (Da etimologia e uso da palavra; o ‘habitat’ e a servidão voluntária dos chatos). Revista Espaço Acadêmio, n. 49, junho/2005. >](http://www.espacoacademico.com.br/049/49lima.htm)</sub>

Em [*Tratado Geral dos Chatos* (1993, Guilherme Figueiredo](http://5.pdfmedia.co/18301433/tratado-geral-dos-chatos.html) (*apud* [Mario Americo de Moura Filho](http://cafehistoria.ning.com/m/blogpost?id=1980410%3ABlogPost%3A598259)) diz:

> Já quanto a etimologia e uso da palavra, não coube ao Guilherme a invenção, até porque não se trata de uma invenção, mas de um vocábulo que designa a irritação que os pediculídeos costumam provocar nos seres humanos.
>   
>   Os etimólogos dizem que a palavra chato provém do nome vulgar dado a um inseto anopluro da família dos pediculídeos (phtirius pubis ou pediculus pubis), um piolho cosmopolita que adora viver nos pelos pubianos e, eventualmente, nas sobrancelhas e axilas. E se mais pelos houvera, como diria Camões, lá estaria...
>   
>   Essa chatice passou a nomear os humanos, cujo comportamento tem a singular peculiaridade de igualmente irritar os outros humanos.

Comment: Obrigado pela contribuição +1. É pena que os artigos dizem «segundo os etimólogos», mas não indicam o nome de nenhum etimólogo. Já o dicionário Houaiss indica o nome de Antenor Nascentes, que é de opinião contrária, que o piolho se chama chato porque importuna.